Upper Bound on European/American Call Option (Hull)
I recently began reading Hull's derivatives textbook, and found a line that he didn't expand on much. Let $c$ be the price of a European call, $C$ be the price of an American call, and $S_0$ be the current price of the stock underlying the call. Hull then says:

"No matter what happens, the option can never be worth more than the stock. Hence, the stock price is an upper bound to the option price:
$c \leq S_0$ and $C \leq S_0$.
If these relationships were not true, an arbitrageur could easily make a riskless profit by buying the stock and selling the call option."

I had no clue how this would end up in an arbitrage, so I tried prove it myself for the American call case. But when I did, I got something different from what Hull claimed, so I must have made a mistake somewhere:
Suppose the call has strike $K$. Initially, we buy the stock for $S_0$ and write the call for $c$, so that we currently have $C-S_0$. At maturity, the stock's price has changed to $S_T$, so that so far, we have $C + (S_T - S_0)$.
Now, we either have $K < S_T$ or $K \geq S_T$. Consider the case where $K \geq S_T$. In this case, the owner of the call will not exercise, so our final profit is $C + (S_T - S_0)$.
Isn't the final results conditional on $S_T$? How does this make the profit riskless?

I don't agree that the final results are conditional on $S_T$. The whole point of a covered call (short call long underlying), is to hold the asset in the event the option counterparty exercises the call i.e. $S_T>K$ as you have mentioned. You are not expected to sell the underlying asset when it is worth $S_T$. Therefore, the expression $C+(S_T-S_0)$ is erroneous.
The riskless profit will therefore always be given by:
$$C-S_0$$

I can sort of see the reasoning here - when you say that the profit will be $C - S_0$, do you mean the amount you hold in cash only? Because if the counterparty does not exercise, we still hold a stock worth $S_T$, in addition to the $C$ we obtained from writing the call, and the $-S_0$ from buying the stock in the beginning.

Yes. In that case, you would have a greater cashflow (where your expression is right), but we don't usually consider the period after maturity of the option (where you sell the asset and generate cashflows).

If you found my comments to be helpful, I would appreciate an upvote on my solution (or acceptance as answer unless you already have accepted another as the answer), thanks!

Oh yeah sfor sure - your solution was very helpful, thank you so much!
